No suitable test found in -path- Nunit - Visual Studio Mac
I am trying to use nunitTestAdapter in Visual Studio Mac, but when trying to debug a test I see the following error in Test tab(screenshot attatched):

The operation failed due to an internal error, no suitable test found
in -path- either assembly contains no test or proper test driver has
been not found.


Regarding the Nugget Packages, I have NUnit 4.1.0 and NUnit3TestAdapter 4.5.0.
My project's platform target is x64 instead of Any CPU, as setting it to Any CPU generates a different error for nunit regarding the compatibility of the framework, which by default seems to be targeting x32.
This is the test I am trying to execute:
using System;
using HackRankPractice.Problems;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Legacy;

namespace HackRankPractice.Test
{
    public class TestConstructArray
    {
        [Test]
        public void GetMaxCombinations()
        {
            //ARRANGE
            ConstructTheArray constructTheArray = new ConstructTheArray();

            //ACT
            long result = 1;

            //ASSERT
            ClassicAssert.AreEqual(1, result);
        }
    }
}

Do you know what might be happening? If you need more information let me know and I will provide it as soon as I see your request.
